# How can I get the original Message on a splitter AggregateStrategy

Tags: java, apache-camel

in my route i use a Splitter to split the Positions in single Messages. The single Message are enrich with some data. After the split I want to merge all messages to one. But when I do this, I get only all Positions, not the border XML.

My XML:

```
<order>
    <firstname>Max</firstname>
    <lastname>Mustermann</lastname>
    <positions>
        <position>
            <articlename>Article 1</articlename>
            <amount>1</amount>
        </position>
        <position>
            <articlename>Article 2</articlename>
            <amount>2</amount>
        </position>
    </positions>
</order>
```

My Route:

```
from("activemq:orders")
    .split(body().tokenizeXML("POSITION",""), new AggregatePositionsStrategy())
        .enrich("direct:getArticleNumber", new addArticleNrToPositionStrategy())
    .end()
    .to("file://c:/temp")
```

After the Route my XML is:

```
        <position>
            <articlenumber>654321</articlenumber>
            <articlename>Article 1</articlename>
            <amount>1</amount>
        </position>
        <position>
            <articlenumber>123456</articlenumber>
            <articlename>Article 2</articlename>
            <amount>2</amount>
        </position>
```

New data are inserted, but the order-Border is lost. What can I do to get all Data?

My AggregatePositionsStrategy for the Splitter is:

```
public class AggregatePositionsStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange exchange, Exchange response) {

        if (exchange == null) {
            return response;
        }

        if (exchange.getIn().getHeader("Artikelnummer") != null && exchange.getIn().getHeader("Artikelnummer").equals("Not Found")) {
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("Artikelnummer", "Not Found");
        }

        if (response.getIn().getHeader("Artikelnummer") != null && response.getIn().getHeader("Artikelnummer").equals("Not Found")) {
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("Artikelnummer", "Not Found");
        }

        String orders = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String newLine = response.getIn().getBody(String.class);

        orders = orders + "\n" + newLine;
        exchange.getIn().setBody(orders);

        return exchange;
    }
}
```

I know, I copy only the Bodys from the splitted Messages. But I don't know how I can get the original Message, to get all parts. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i write my own Processor. It is to difficult to solve this with Camel build-in methods.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: 
you can always get original body of the route with UnitOfWork interface

```
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message originalMessage = (Message)
                exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage();

        (do something...)
    }       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the original message is indeed "lost" when you use the `splitter` pattern.

You can save it as a property on the exchange, and use it again later to replace the message body, with the updated positions list.

```
from("activemq:orders")
    .setProperty("OriginalMessage", body())
    .split(body().tokenizeXML("POSITION",""), new AggregatePositionsStrategy())
        .enrich("direct:getArticleNumber", new addArticleNrToPositionStrategy())
    .end()
    // set the positions on the "OriginalMessage" and set it to the body here
    .to("file://c:/temp")
```

Alternatively you could just save "FirstName" and "LastName" to exchange properties and reconstruct a new Order message.

Comment: If I don't use an AggregateStrategy. I get the original Message Body after the Split, but with no enriched data. http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html#Splitter-WhattheSplitterreturns so there must be the original Message body everywhere